# Play only VAST Video without primary video using JW player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, jwplayer

I am using JW player to play video. I set up vast Tag following Manner

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("player1");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "sample.mp4",
    width: "100%",
    displaytitle: false,
    controls: true,
    primary: 'html5',
    mute:'false',
    autostart: false,
    advertising: {
          client: "vast",
          tag: 'http://ad4.liverail.com/?LR_PUBLISHER_ID=1331&LR_CAMPAIGN_ID=229&LR_SCHEMA=vast2-vpaid'
        }
```

The vast video plays infront of the primary video (sample.mp4). Now i need to play only VAST video without primary video. and also need to capture all events for Ad Video. is this possible?? please Help.

[**Fiddle Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/bwcsdg1u/1/)

Comment: Which version of the player are you using? A valid advertising license is required to play VAST ads.

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1431665

Answer (score 0):

JW Player doesn't offer an ads-only player, so you'll have to load blank.mp4 in order to play the preroll ad.

Answer (score 0):

@ Josie Keller

I am able to play just the Ad by targeting a "blank.mp4" (which may be an actual file or a false reference) Either way, it works fine on desktop systems, including OSX and Windows.

I simply use listeners to do something else, like so...
    jwplayer("advertisement").on('adSkipped',function(){next()})
    jwplayer("advertisement").on('adComplete',function(){next()})
    jwplayer("advertisement").on('adError',function(){next()})
    jwplayer("advertisement").on('error',function(){next()})
    jwplayer("advertisement").on('play',function(){next()})

However!...

The ads do **not** play on either iOS or Android, regardless of whether the blank.mp4 points to an actual file or not. The ad is skipped entirely. Is there something I need to do to get this operational on mobile? I am using  primary: 'html5' as well so I don't see what's causing the ad not to show on mobile...